# My event ajax keydown is too slow

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem with a h:inputText and i don't know how to solve it.

I'm working on a xhtml page using JSF and RichFaces which contains fields as Calendar, SelectOneMenu, InputTextArea, Input. At the end of my form, there are two buttons Print and Save.

If one of the fields is modified (text, date, etc), i have to disable the Print button. In every field, i have add ajax event.

For example :

```
<rich:calendar datePattern="dd/MM/yyyy" timeZone="#{timeZone.timeZone}" value="#{myBean.date}">
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.verifyModification}" render="myForm"/>
</rich:calendar>
```

If my date is changed, i call a method stored in my bean and it's ok.

But, i have a problem with my inputText and inputTextArea.

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.name}" maxlength="50">
    <a4j:ajax event="keydown" render="myForm" listener="#{myBean.verifyName}" />
</h:inputText>
```

If i write fastly, for example i stay on the letter a to write aaaaaaaa in my field. The field will contain aaaaaaaa then aaaa. Is it because the ajax event is too slow? The problem doesn't come from my bean method because i only test a value.

Because of that, i can't test this field. I have tried the others events like blur, change. If i use these events, i have to click out of my field then my button is refresh.

Could you help me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not know JSF, but wouldn't your implementation communicate with the server on each key pressed? So you would face network latency each time, which might produce the delay.

Comment: Yes, i communicated with the server on each key pressed. But i solve the problem by rendering only my button panel and not all my form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you `render` your complete form, not only the part of it that needs updating. JSF will then replace your form with the values you submitted *on the first ajax request*. Try:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.name}">
    <f:ajax event="keydown" render="myButtonP" listener="#{bean.verifyName}" />
</h:inputText>

<h:panelGroup id="myButtonP">
    <h:commandButton id="printBtn" value="Print" action="#{bean.printMe}" 
        disabled="#{bean.canPrint}" />
    <h:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Save" action="#{bean.save}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

If you use `disabled` instead of `rendered` on the button, you can even reference `printBtn` directly in the `render` attribute.

Comment: Thank you guy. By rendering only my panel, the problem is gone.